# Adding a matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, legend-properties

How can one create a legend for a line graph in Matplotlib's PyPlot without creating any extra variables?

Please consider the graphing script below:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    PyPlot.plot(length, bubble, 'b-',
                length, ins, 'r-',
                length, merge_r, 'g+',
                length, merge_i, 'p-', )
    PyPlot.title("Combined Statistics")
    PyPlot.xlabel("Length of list (number)")
    PyPlot.ylabel("Time taken (seconds)")
    PyPlot.show()
```

As you can see, this is a very basic use of matplotlib's PyPlot. This generates the following graph:

[image: Graph]

However, it is unclear which line is which. Thus, I need a legend; however, taking a look at the following example below ([from the official site](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html)):

```
ax = subplot(1,1,1)
p1, = ax.plot([1,2,3], label="line 1")
p2, = ax.plot([3,2,1], label="line 2")
p3, = ax.plot([2,3,1], label="line 3")

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

# reverse the order
ax.legend(handles[::-1], labels[::-1])

# or sort them by labels
import operator
hl = sorted(zip(handles, labels), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
handles2, labels2 = zip(*hl)

ax.legend(handles2, labels2)
```

You will see that I need to create an extra variable `ax`. How can I add a legend to my graph *without* having to create this extra variable and retaining the simplicity of my current script?

Comment: I am confused by your concern of creating an extra variable.  You have to make those objects behind the scenes anyway.

Comment: @tcaswell Well let me try to assuage them. I do not want to create extra variables, because it adds complexity to the whole script. I'm trying to _teach_ this to a bunch of students, and since they have't used `matplotlib` before, I wanted to keep things as simple as possible. Also, if you take a look at Rob's answer, its far simpler than the example shown on the website. I hope that helps.

Comment: I would argue that using the state machine interface makes it _harder_ to understand in the long run because so much of it is being done 'by magic'.  Also, the convention is to use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` instead of `PyPlot`

Answer (score 832, accepted):

Add a `label=` to each of your [`plot()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) calls, and then call [`legend(loc='upper left')`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend).

Consider this sample (tested with Python 3.8.0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 1000)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

plt.plot(x, y1, "-b", label="sine")
plt.plot(x, y2, "-r", label="cosine")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.ylim(-1.5, 2.0)
plt.show()
```

[image]
Slightly modified from this tutorial: http://jakevdp.github.io/mpl_tutorial/tutorial_pages/tut1.html

Comment: Is there a way to do this if you don't know the labels at the time the series is plotted? I.e. a way to add labels to a series after it has already been plotted? Or maybe a way to modify placeholder labels before showing the legend?

Comment: `plt.legend(loc='upper left')` also works, where `plt` is from `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Comment: Note for others: the `plt.legend()` call **needs** to be **after** `plt.plot(label="lab1")`

Comment: @davidA Yes, you can simply pass a list of strings into [`plt.legend`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html): `plt.legend(['First Label', 'Second Label'])`

Comment: I am sure actual documentation at: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html also answers this, but it is such a pain to get that info from there as compared to here. We need to re-imagine documentation. lolz

Answer (score 63):

You can access the Axes instance (`ax`) with `plt.gca()`.  In this case, you can use

```
plt.gca().legend()
```

You can do this either by using the `label=` keyword in each of your `plt.plot()` calls or by assigning your labels as a tuple or list within `legend`, as in this working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(-0.75,1,100)
y0 = np.exp(2 + 3*x - 7*x**3)
y1 = 7-4*np.sin(4*x)
plt.plot(x,y0,x,y1)
plt.gca().legend(('y0','y1'))
plt.show()
```

[image: pltGcaLegend]

However, if you need to access the Axes instance more that once, I do recommend saving it to the variable `ax` with

```
ax = plt.gca()
```

and then calling `ax` instead of `plt.gca()`.

Comment: copy-paste answer that doesn't require any reading, and with a picture! this answer deserves more credit

Answer (score 29):

You can add a custom legend [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html)

```
first = [1, 2, 4, 5, 4]
second = [3, 4, 2, 2, 3]
plt.plot(first, 'g--', second, 'r--')
plt.legend(['First List', 'Second List'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 28):

Here's an example to help you out ...

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('ADR vs Rating (CS:GO)')
ax.scatter(x=data[:,0],y=data[:,1],label='Data')
plt.plot(data[:,0], m*data[:,0] + b,color='red',label='Our Fitting 
Line')
ax.set_xlabel('ADR')
ax.set_ylabel('Rating')
ax.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm just curious, why is your fitting line so far off the data?

Answer (score 15):

A simple plot for sine and cosine curves with a legend.

Used `matplotlib.pyplot`

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[]
for i in range(-314,314):
    x.append(i/100)
ysin=[math.sin(i) for i in x]
ycos=[math.cos(i) for i in x]
plt.plot(x,ysin,label='sin(x)')  #specify label for the corresponding curve
plt.plot(x,ycos,label='cos(x)')
plt.xticks([-3.14,-1.57,0,1.57,3.14],['-$\pi$','-$\pi$/2',0,'$\pi$/2','$\pi$'])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Sin and Cosine plots (click to view image)]

Answer (score 10):

Add labels to each argument in your plot call corresponding to the series it is graphing, i.e. `label = "series 1"`

Then simply add `Pyplot.legend()` to the bottom of your script and the legend will display these labels.

Comment: This is the right idea, but you never add the labels so the legend will be empty

Answer (score 1):

#### Explicitly passing handles and labels

Going off of OP's code where a bunch of lines were drawn with a single `plot()` call, we can still add a legend afterwards. With `pyplot.plot`, all lines are drawn on a single Axes object which can be accessed via `plt.gca().lines`. In the example code below, `print(plt.gca().lines)` outputs `<Axes.ArtistList of 4 lines>`. This list contains all the lines drawn on the Axes in the order they were drawn. Also, since this is a list, it can be unpacked into separate variables. So you can reorder them however you want and pass them as the first argument along with the corresponding labels list as the second argument to `plt.legend()`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-0.7, 1, 100)
y0 = 13 - np.exp(1-2*x)
y1 = 7 - 4*np.sin(4*x)
y2 = np.random.default_rng(0).normal(8, 3, 100)

plt.plot(
    x, y0, 'b--', 
    x, y1, 'r-',
    x, x+14, 'k',
    x, y2, 'g+'
)

exp, sine, line, normal = plt.gca().lines   # unpack the list
plt.legend([line, normal, exp, sine], ['line', 'normal', 'exp', 'sine']);
```

[image: img1]

#### Labeling existing plots

You can also pass a list of labels to the `legend()` call to label existing plots (without the handles). The labels in the list must be ordered in the order the corresponding plot is plotted. This method is especially useful if you use a third-party library that uses matplotlib in the backend but doesn't have a `label=` parameter in the plotting function call. In other words, you can label plots after it is plotted. However, make sure to get the order right.

```py
plt.plot(x, y0, 'b--', x, y1, 'r-')
plt.plot(x, x+14, c='k')
plt.scatter(x, y2, c='g', marker='+', linewidths=1)
plt.legend(['exp', 'sine', 'line', 'normal']);
```