# How to plot and annotate grouped bars in seaborn / matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

I have used a barplot to represent the subscribers for each row. This is what I did:

```
data = channels.sort_values('subscribers', ascending=False).head(5)
chart = sns.barplot(x = 'name', y='subscribers',data=data)
chart.set_xticklabels(chart.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
for p in chart.patches:
    chart.annotate("{:,.2f}".format(p.get_height(), '.2f'), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()), ha = 'center', va = 'center', xytext = (0, 10), textcoords = 'offset points')
```

[image]

Now I want to show the 'video_count' for each user on this same plot. The goal is to compare how the number of subscribers relate to the number of videos. How can I depict this on the chart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Data

- The data needs to be converted to a long format using [`.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html)
- Because of the scale of values, `'log'` is used for the [`yscale`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html)
- All of the categories in `'cats'` are included for the example.

  - Select only the desired columns before melting, or use `dfl = dfl[dfl.cats.isin(['sub', 'vc'])` to filter for the desired `'cats'`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# setup dataframe
data = {'vc': [76, 47, 140, 106, 246],
        'tv': [29645400, 28770702, 50234486, 30704017, 272551386],
        'sub': [66100, 15900, 44500, 37000, 76700],
        'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    vc        tv    sub name
0   76  29645400  66100    a
1   47  28770702  15900    b
2  140  50234486  44500    c

# convert to long form
dfl = (df.melt(id_vars='name', var_name='cats', value_name='values')
       .sort_values('values', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True))

  name cats     values
0    e   tv  272551386
1    c   tv   50234486
2    d   tv   30704017
```

### Updated as of `matplotlib v3.4.2`

- Use [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html)
- **`.bar_label` works for `matplotlib`, `seaborn`, and `pandas` plots.**
- See [How to add value labels on a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for additional details and examples with `.bar_label`.
- Tested with `seaborn v0.11.1`, which is using `matplotlib` as the plot engine.

```py
# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
sns.barplot(x='name', y='values', data=dfl, hue='cats', ax=ax)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=0)
ax.set_yscale('log')

for c in ax.containers:
    # set the bar label
    ax.bar_label(c, fmt='%.0f', label_type='edge', padding=1)
    
# pad the spacing between the number and the edge of the figure
ax.margins(y=0.1)
```

[image]

### Plot with `seaborn v0.11.1`

- Using `matplotlib` before version 3.4.2
- Note that using `.annotate` and `.patches` is much more verbose than with `.bar_label`.

```py
# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
sns.barplot(x='name', y='values', data=dfl, hue='cats', ax=ax)
ax.set_xticklabels(chart.get_xticklabels(), rotation=0)
ax.set_yscale('log')

for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(f"{p.get_height():.0f}", (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
                ha='center', va='center', xytext =(0, 7), textcoords='offset points')
```