# Bar chart help in python with value label alignment in the center

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I use the below code in order to display the bar chart.

**CODE**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

#creating the dataset
data = {'apples':20,'Mangoes':15,'Lemon':30,'Oranges':10}
names = list(data.keys())
values = list(data.values())

bars = plt.bar(names, height=values, width=0.9)
for bar in bars:
    yval = bar.get_height()
    plt.text(bar.get_x(), yval + .005, yval)
plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = True
plt.show()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

My requirement is i want the labels aligned in the center of each bar and has to sorted in descending order. Looking for **Output** like below.

[image]

Comment: Are you using `pandas` or just `matplotlib`?

Comment: just ```matplotlib```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include multiple data columns in a seaborn barplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63220741/how-to-include-multiple-data-columns-in-a-seaborn-barplot)

Comment: Seaborn is just an api for matplotlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort use:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#creating the dataset
data = {'apples':20,'Mangoes':15,'Lemon':30,'Oranges':10}
names, values = zip(*sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))

bars = plt.bar(names, height=values, width=0.9)
for bar in bars:
    yval = bar.get_height()
    plt.text(bar.get_x(), yval + .005, yval)
plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = True
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code to fix your problem. [your arbitrary bar chart figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkFYP.png)

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = {'apples' : 20, 'Mangoes' : 15,
    'Lemon' : 30, 'oranges' : 10}

# we apply asterisk sign on a list of tuples which is returened by 
# sorted() function.
names, values = zip(*sorted(data.items(), key= lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))

plt.figure()
plt.bar(names, values, width=0.9)

# add Bar labels
for c in plt.gca().containers:
   plt.gca().bar_label(c)

plt.show()
```

Called with a BarContainer artist, add a label to each bar, which, by default, is data value, so exactly what you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That answer to an old question brings something new, indeed (I mention it, because I saw it while reviewing new answers to old question. An activity which is mostly about saying endlessly "this answer brings nothing new" :-)). Nevertheless, I wonder, why not apply the same idea, simply to the artist returned by `plt.bar`. `plt.bar_label(plt.bar(name, value, widht=0.9))` gives the exact same result on my machine. Without the need to iterate through all `gca().containers`, and with the guarantee, if other things were plotted, that only those bars are impacted.