# Legend in maptplotlib plot not appearing

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below code :

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pylab import plt #load plot library
# indicate the output of plotting function is printed to the notebook
%matplotlib inline 

data = [(68825, '2019-12-15 01:00:00'),
 (69525, '2019-12-15 02:00:00'),
 (71115, '2019-12-15 03:00:00'),
 (62642, '2019-12-15 04:00:00'),
 (69204, '2019-12-15 05:00:00'),
 (67871, '2019-12-15 06:00:00'),
 (72129, '2019-12-15 07:00:00'),
 (69078, '2019-12-15 08:00:00'),
 (60784, '2019-12-15 09:00:00'),
 (66923, '2019-12-15 10:00:00'),
 (76046, '2019-12-15 11:00:00'),
 (76789, '2019-12-15 12:00:00'),
 (82369, '2019-12-15 13:00:00'),
 (80702, '2019-12-15 14:00:00'),
 (70129, '2019-12-15 15:00:00'),
 (45318, '2019-12-15 16:00:00'),
 (41048, '2019-12-15 17:00:00'),
 (30628, '2019-12-15 18:00:00'),
 (26311, '2019-12-15 19:00:00'),
 (24802, '2019-12-15 20:00:00'),
 (28799, '2019-12-15 21:00:00'),
 (29195, '2019-12-15 22:00:00')]

data1 = [(8825, '2019-12-15 01:00:00'),
 (6955, '2019-12-15 02:00:00'),
 (7115, '2019-12-15 03:00:00'),
 (6642, '2019-12-15 04:00:00'),
 (9204, '2019-12-15 05:00:00'),
 (6787, '2019-12-15 06:00:00'),
 (7219, '2019-12-15 07:00:00'),
 (6978, '2019-12-15 08:00:00'),
 (6784, '2019-12-15 09:00:00'),
 (6692, '2019-12-15 10:00:00'),
 (7606, '2019-12-15 11:00:00'),
 (7689, '2019-12-15 12:00:00'),
 (8369, '2019-12-15 13:00:00'),
 (702, '2019-12-15 14:00:00'),
 (7019, '2019-12-15 15:00:00'),
 (4518, '2019-12-15 16:00:00'),
 (4148, '2019-12-15 17:00:00'),
 (3628, '2019-12-15 18:00:00'),
 (2311, '2019-12-15 19:00:00'),
 (2802, '2019-12-15 20:00:00'),
 (2799, '2019-12-15 21:00:00'),
 (2195, '2019-12-15 22:00:00')]

data_x = [x[1].split(" ")[1].split(":")[0] for x in data]
data_y = [x[0] for x in data]

data1_x = [x[1].split(" ")[1].split(":")[0] for x in data1]
data1_y = [x[0] for x in data1]

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [14, 7]

plt.scatter(data_x, data_y, marker='o' , label="test 1")
plt.scatter(data1_x, data1_y, marker='x' , label="test 2")
```

renders :

[image]

How to display labels associated with each plot ?

Using code :

```
plt.scatter(data_x, data_y, marker='o' , label="test 1")
plt.scatter(data1_x, data1_y, marker='x' , label="test 2")
```

does not render the labels "test 1" and "test 2"

Comment: `plt.legend()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a legend to PyPlot in Matplotlib in the most simple manner possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125722/adding-a-legend-to-pyplot-in-matplotlib-in-the-most-simple-manner-possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `plt.legend()` to the end of your code.

```py
plt.scatter(data_x, data_y, marker='o' , label="test 1")
plt.scatter(data1_x, data1_y, marker='x' , label="test 2")
plt.legend()
```

[image]