# How to add two different labels to legend for an overlap plot using matplotlib in python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, legend

Okay this might be easy even I search on web but could not get it. Basically i want to add the two different labels to my plot and this is my line of code for that

```
plt.plot(x[:,1],y,'ro',x[:,1],Line_fit,'b',linewidth=0.5,markersize=4,label="training data") # plot the data 
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
```

but I am getting following result in which has same labels for both the plot.as following

[image]

Even I tried this

```
plt.plot(x[:,1],y,'ro',x[:,1],Line_fit,'b',linewidth=0.5,markersize=4,label="training data",label="Linear Regression") # plot the data
```

but give the error:

```
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated
```

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125722/adding-a-legend-to-pyplot-in-matplotlib-in-the-simplest-manner-possible) guide for the simple way but here `plt.plot()`had used twice in the accepted answer.My question is how can i do it the same thing in single line code as I did in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two lines. One for the plot, one for the legend.

```
plt.plot(x[:,1], y, 'ro', x[:,1], Line_fit, 'b', linewidth=0.5, markersize=4)
plt.legend(["training data", "Linear Regression"], loc="upper left")
```