# How to title a matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have a figure with multiple legends and I would like to be able to label them.
I would like to put a title/label `Some label` on the legend, as shown below. This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125722/adding-a-legend-to-pyplot-in-matplotlib-in-the-simplest-manner-possible) answer which only states how to place a legend on the figure.

I have checked the [legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html) but can't find any info on how to do this.

[image]

Again, please don't close this question (as was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63023389/how-to-put-a-label-on-a-matplotlib-legend) one) it's not a duplicate of the answer linked above. That answer does not give any information on adding a label/title to a legend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend), you can place a title with the `title` option in the `legend` command. For example:

```
plt.plot([0,1], label='A')
plt.legend(title='title')
```

Or with axis instance:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0,1], label='A')
ax.legend(title='title')
```

Output:

[image]