# Matplotlib Label issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

I have dataframe and would like to plot the histogram for 2 variables. Below syntax gives the required plot however labels do not appear. Any help would appreciate.

```
colors = ['tan', 'lime']
labels = ['Score 1','Score 2']
plt.hist([test.score_1,test.score_2],bins = 10,histtype='bar',color=colors, label=labels)
```

Here is the plot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wki6.png)

Comment: You can call `plt.legend(labels=labels)` after `plt.hist`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a legend to PyPlot in Matplotlib in the simplest manner possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125722/adding-a-legend-to-pyplot-in-matplotlib-in-the-simplest-manner-possible)