# How can I label a plot using a mix of a variable and string?

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

I'm running into trouble when trying to label individual plots (inside a loop) using a mix of variables and strings.

Here is the section I'm having trouble with:

```
plt.plot(wlist, elist, label=('ratio =',i)) #using this inside a loop
```

When I run it, it shows up on the legend as ('ratio =', #) where the # is whatever iteration it is on. I only want it to print as:

```
Ratio = #
```

(The parenthesis I added are part of the output I'm getting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parentheses aren't needed, then you can pass an `f-string` to the `label` argument (you can read more about f-strings [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) if you haven't used them before):

```
plt.plot(wlist, elist, label=f'ratio ={i}')
```

Here is a quick example borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125722/adding-a-legend-to-pyplot-in-matplotlib-in-the-simplest-manner-possible) where we can label some curves based on the iteration number:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 20, 1000)
y_plots = [np.sin(x), np.cos(x)]
for i in range(len(y_plots)):
    plt.plot(x, y_plots[i], label=f"plot {i}")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]